# feedback on re-design scene from [Rec]

Tags: feedback, horror

Hello. I'm a wannabe sound designer. All times i'm trying to learn as much as i can by reading, watching, listening and trying. Before I start working with young filmmakers in no-budget productions, I want to build my portfolio by re-designing the sound of my favourite movies. So here is one of those. I recorded everything by myself with a Zoom H4 and a Rode NT1 (except guns). The most difficult part was ADR as I havent got professional actors to record the dialogues. I would appreciate any feedback.

so here it is---
[rec redesign](http://vimeo.com/19055196)

thanks.
Maciej.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very nice!

Can i suggest just the bullet casings falling after the shots?
And maybe putting some bullhorn shouting outside, as well as a bit more reverb on the sirens,
and in the end muffling the girl's sighs just a little and a bit of verb, bit since her back is turned to the camera (unless the idea is that she's wearing a lav)

nice work!

Answer (score 1):

Great work.

Apart from what @Filipe said, I did find that the initial "moan" sound was a bit to omni-directional. It needs to give a bit more feel for the space (doesn't seem to mesh with the reverb you used on the actors). Also as above the sirens need either a longer loop or some randomly different sounds (honks, etc) to break up the loop. Maybe mute it more and give it just the smallest pan to the right (so it feels more like it outside).